Why we cannot enable transferfee config or enable metadata after minting on token 2022?
We were trying to enable transfer fee config after minting a token22 token using realloc instruction, but it was not working!
We then tried to enable the transferfee config on minting and later tried to enable the metadata extension using realloc instruction, seems like its not working either!
But realloc instruction works perfectly only with enableRequireMemo extension
This is the code we have created for anyone to check what we are facing.

Most mint extensions cannot be added after the mint is initialized because they fundamentally alter how the token operates. If people are already using a token, and all of a sudden the mint creator adds a 100% transfer fee, that would be a bad experience for the user!
So you must initialize all extensions before initializing the base mint.
